# gdal WriteArray() crashes python without a stack trace

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I'm trying to write an array to a geotiff using gdal. Each row of the array is identical, and I used np.broadcast_to to create the array.

When I try to write it, the I get a windows popup saying "Python has stopped working: A problem cause the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program"

This approximates the steps I'm taking:

```
import gdal
import numpy as np

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create("C:/raster.tif", 1000, 1000, 1, 6)
band = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)

# Create  array 
a = np.arange(0,1000, dtype='float32')
a1 = np.broadcast_to(a, (1000,1000))

# try writing
band.WriteArray(a1) # crash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the input array created by broadcast_to isn't contiguous on disk.  As described in the [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to), more than one element array may point to the same memory address. This causes problems in gdal.

Instead of using broadcast_to, use something that stores each element as its own place in memory.
As an illustrative example, see the following code:

```
import gdal
import numpy as np
import sys

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create("C:/raster.tif", 1000, 1000, 1, 6)
band = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)

# Create 1000 x 1000 array two different ways
a = np.arange(0,1000, dtype='float32')
a1 = a[np.newaxis, :]
a1 = a1.repeat(1000, axis=0)

a2 = np.broadcast_to(a, (1000,1000))

# examine size of objects
sys.getsizeof(a1) # 4000112
sys.getsizeof(a2) # 112

# try writing
band.WriteArray(a1) # writes fine
band.WriteArray(a2) # crash
```